# Updating array element by reassigning it to different variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, reference

First of all, sorry if this was asked before, but I simply could not find anything related to it.

```cs
string anElement = "World";
string[] col = new string[2] { "Hello", anElement };
anElement = "Jupiter";
Array.ForEach(col, Console.WriteLine);

// Output:
// Hello
// World
```

As can be seen, reassigning a different value to the `anElement` reference doesn't update the value.

Same also applies in this scenario:

```cs
string[] col = new string[2] { "Hello", "World" };
string elementToUpdate = col[1];
elementToUpdate = "Jupiter";
Array.ForEach(col, Console.WriteLine);
```

If all the elements are stored as references, why changing `col[1]="Jupiter"` works while the above does not?

Answer (score 0):

Because local variable string **anElement** assigned is not used in any execution path.
Try this code instead

```
        string anElement = "World";
        anElement = "Jupiter";
        string[] col = new string[2] { "Hello", anElement };
        Array.ForEach(col, Console.WriteLine);

        // Output:
        // Hello
        // Jupiter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead

```
string anElement = "World";
string[] col = new string[2] { "Hello", anElement };
col[1] = "Jupiter";
Array.ForEach(col, Console.WriteLine);
```

The problem is you were assigning the value to the anElement, and not getting the item within the array where you needed to make the change